# List Files With Extensions Contained In Array

Tags: android

I would like to list image files from FTP with extensions defined in an array, I can check if an array contains a certain string but can't do the reverse of checking if part of a file (extension) is contained in an array, I tried:

```
        String ftpFileName;
        String[] extImage = {".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png", ".bmp", ".gif", ".tiff"};
        String[] listNames = client.listNames();
        for (int i = 0; i < listNames.length; i++) {

            ftpFileName = listNames[i];

            if (ftpFileName.contains(Arrays.asList(extImage)))
            {
                //here I will handle the returned image file names
            }
        }
```

Seems like I can only do this `Arrays.asList(extImage).contains(ftpFileName)` but need the reverse of this since I'm only checking a "part" of the file name from array.

Comment: Determine the extension of ftpFileName. After that make a loop to compare with the extensions in your string array.

Comment: Or: Arrays.asList(extImage).contains(extension of ftpFileName)